# How can I change different URL or view in tabbed activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-tabbed-activity

I'm new in Android kotlin development. I would like to create a tabbed activity in my app to show different static HTML page.

I able to set 1 URL in my app now. But when I change or tap to another tab, it will show similar view or URL.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.webkit.WebView
import xxx.abcabc.xxx.R
import android.util.Log


class PlaceholderFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var pageViewModel: PageViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel::class.java).apply {
            setIndex(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1)
        }


    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_left_menu_policies, container, false)

        var webTnc: WebView = root.findViewById(R.id.myWebView)
        webTnc.loadUrl("https://www.abcxyz.com/abcxyz/abcxyz_webpage/tnc.html")


        return root
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private const val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(sectionNumber: Int): PlaceholderFragment {
            return PlaceholderFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How can I detect sectionNumber something like

```
if(sectionNumber == 0)
{
 var webTnc: WebView = root.findViewById(R.id.myWebView)
    webTnc.loadUrl("https://www.abcxyz.com/abcxyz/abcxyz_webpage/tnc.html")
}
else
{
var webTnc: WebView = root.findViewById(R.id.myWebView)
    webTnc.loadUrl("https://www.URL2.com/URL2.html")
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

**Edited**
[image]

Comment: In your adapter while changing the fragments, pass the position through bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're putting `sectionNumber` in bundle arguments in fragment. So you can use that `arguments` to get the data back.

Try this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_left_menu_policies, container, false)
    val sectionNumber = arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1
    if (sectionNumber == 1) {
        var webTnc: WebView = root.findViewById(R.id.myWebView)
        webTnc.loadUrl("https://www.abcxyz.com/abcxyz/abcxyz_webpage/tnc.html")
    } else {
        var webTnc: WebView = root.findViewById(R.id.myWebView)
        webTnc.loadUrl("https://www.URL2.com/URL2.html")
    }


    return root
}
```

Comment: I tried to apply yr suggestion but getting error "Unresolved reference: sectionNumber". Any idea?

Comment: I did a silly mistake. I corrected by answer. Use this line `val sectionNumber = arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1`

Comment: Hi Birju, after applied your code, both tabs will show same result. May I know which part I did wrong? You may refer to screen as attached above.

Comment: Finally its work when I change `if (sectionNumber == 0) {` to `if (sectionNumber == 1) {`.